# How do I add confirmation to YesNoCheckboxCellEditor in slickgrid?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have a checkbox field in **slickgrid** that uses *YesNoCheckboxCellEditor* and wants user to confirm the change. I have tried adding *vildator:myMethod* to it but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have to modify this function

```
this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
                item[args.column.field] = state;
            };
```

in your editor. So you just put whatever conditional logic you need and then apply value if needed.

```
this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
         var applyValue = (...<your logic goes here>...);
         if (!!applyValue){          
             item[args.column.field] = state;
         }
};
```